# jQuery find an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I have a div as so:

```
<div class="country"> 
    <div class="cty_popover">
        <p>TITLE</p>
        <ul>
            <li>NAME 1</li>
            <li>NAME 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <img src="resources/images/map-marker.png" alt=" ">
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.country img').hover(function() {
        $(this).parents('.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
    },
    function() {
        $('.cty_popover').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

I know this line is wrong in the jQuery:

```
$(this).find('.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
```

I need to target:

```
.cty_popover
```

from within the function:

```
$('.country img').hover
```

So basically my question is:

How do I target `.cty_popover` using `$(this)`? I need to move up from the 'img' to target it, but not sure how?

I have a lot of these `.cty_popover` divs and that's why I want to use `$(this)` so I don't target them all.

Anyone any ideas why I can't get this working?

Thanks

Comment: You can use selector overload for search in another element like $(whereSelector, whatSelector)

Answer (score 0):

As the `img` is a *sibling* of the `cty_popover`, you can target it using the [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function - see a demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // hide all `cty_popover` sections initially
  $('.cty_popover').hide();

  // hover listener
  $('.country img').hover(function() {
      $(this).prev('.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
    }, function() {
      $(this).prev('.cty_popover').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="country">
  <div class="cty_popover">
    <p>TITLE</p>
    <ul>
      <li>NAME 1</li>
      <li>NAME 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for that. Was struggling for an hour.

Comment: @Zaas could you please accept the answer and close the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the **img** node is a sibling of the **cty_popover** node, replacing this line

```
$(this).parents('.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
```

with this should work

```
$(this).siblings('.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/5m1muz7j/) an example

Answer (score 0):

You should use siblings: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

See this example working on your HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.country').children('img').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings( '.cty_popover').fadeIn(800);
    },
    function() {
        $('.cty_popover').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

```css
.country {
    position. relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.country > img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.country .cty_popover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,0,.9);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 285px;
}
.country .cty_popover:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid rgba(255,255,0,.9);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="country"> 
    <div class="cty_popover">
        <p>TITLE</p>
        <ul>
          <li>NAME 1</li>
          <li>NAME 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/tech" alt=" ">
</div>
```